# Why does $\sum^D_{j=1}w_{ii}^Ax_i^2$ vanish?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices

This question is from Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning:

Exercise 1.14 Show that an arbitrary square matrix with elements $w_{ij}$ can be written in the form $w_{ij}=w^S+{ij}+w^A_{ij}$ where $w^S_{ij}$ and $w^A_{ij}$ are symmetric and anti-symmetric matrices, respectively, satisfying $w_{ij}^S=w_{ji}^S$ and $w_{ij}^A=-w_{ji}^A$ for all $i$ and $j$. Now consider the second order term in a higher order polynomial in $D$ dimensions, given by $$\sum^D_{i=1}\sum^D_{j=1}w_{ij}x_ix_j$$

Show that $$\sum^D_{i=1}\sum^D_{j=1}w_{ij}x_ix_j=\sum^D_{i=1}\sum^D_{j=1}w_{ij}^Sx_ix_j$$

so that the contribution from the anti-symmetric matrix vanishes.

There is a [solution](https://mazeofamazement.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/bishop-1-4-1-7-1-9-1-14-1-40.pdf) from the internet which I saw and I don't completely understand one step. Here's the solution from the beginning:

First we will show that an arbitrary square matrix with elements $w_{ij}$ can be written in the form $w_{ij}=w_{ij}^S+w_{ij}^A$. We can write $w_{ij}$ in two forms:

$$w_{ij}=w_{ij}^S+w_{ij}^A$$

$$w_{ji}=w_{ij}^S-w_{ij}^A$$

so

$$w_{ij}^S=\frac{w_{ij}+w_{ji}}{2}$$

and

$$w_{ij}^A=\frac{w_{ij}-w_{ji}}{2}$$

If we sum them up we can easily see that $w_{ij}=w_{ij}^S+w_{ji}^A holds.

In the next step we'll shwo that $\sum^D_{i=1}\sum^D_{j=1}w_{ij}x_ix_j=\sum^D_{i=1}\sum^D_{j=1}w_{ij}^Sx_ix_j$. So we wish to show that contribution from the anti-symmetric matrix vanishes. Which is equivalent to saying:

$$\sum^D_{i=1}\sum^D_{j=1}w_{ij}^Ax_ix_j=0$$

If we expand the previous, we get:

$$\sum^D_{i=1}\sum^d_{j=1}w_{ij}^Ax_ix_j=\sum^D_{i=1}\sum^D_{j=i+1}w_{ij}^Ax_ix_j+\sum^D_{i=1}\sum^D_{j=i+1}w^A_{ji}x_ix_j+\sum^D_{j=1}w_{ii}^Ax_i^2$$

It is straightforward to see that the last term in the above equation vanishes because $w_{ij}^A=-w^A_{ji}$.

My question is, why does $\sum^D_{j=1}w_{ii}^Ax_i^2$ vanish?

Comment: $w_{ii}^A$ are the diagonal entries of an antisymmetric matrix, so they have to be zero by definition (because $w_{ij}^A = -w_{ji}^A$ means $w_{ii} = -w_{ii}$ when $i = j$).

Comment: Suspect you mean for the last sum of your last display to use the index $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specialize $w_{ij} = -w_{ji}$ by $j \mapsto i$, so we have $w_{ii} = -w_{ii}$.  But the only number equal to its negative is zero, so all the $w_{ii}$ are zero.